# не могу парсить с авторизацией

Tags: python, парсер, post, requests

Всем привет, парсю сайт одной [аптеки](https://apteka.ru/) на python вроде всё правильно делаю, использую сессии, библиотека requests, но каждый раз получаю responce[400]. Post запрос = https://api.apteka.ru/Auth/Auth?cityId=5e57b422a19759000122967b ,

```
import requests
import fake_useragent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()
link = "https://api.apteka.ru/Auth/Auth?cityId=5e57b422a19759000122967b"
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

header = {'user-agent': user}
data = {
    "code": "пароль",
    "group":'null',
    "phone": "номер телефона",
    "referalId": 'null',
    "timeZone": "2",
    "type": "BySms"
}

response = session.post(link, data=data, headers=header, )
print(response)
profile_favorite = 'https://apteka.ru/user/favorite/'
profile_responce = session.get(profile_favorite, headers=header).text

cookies_dic = [
    {"domain": key.domain, "name": key.name, "path": key.path, "value": key.value, }
    for key in session.cookies
]

session2 = requests.Session()

for cookies in cookies_dic:
    session2.cookies.set(**cookies)

resp = session2.get(profile_favorite, headers=header)
```

возможно там есть ещё какая нибудь проверка на пользователя, но если вы что нибудь знаете, то... Заранее спасибо

Comment: сделайте в рамках одной сесcий на досуге почитайте https://docs-python.ru/packages/modul-requests-python/sessii-seansy-session/